# How to tell which files in a shared folder in dropbox were modified by someone else?

Tags: dropbox

I have a shared folder on Dropbox that is owned by my colleague. We both work on the same files. I'd like to know which files have been last modified by him (or even better, modified by him after a certain date) so that I can see what he changed. How can I do this? Thanks.

I can select "View Previous Versions" in Finder, which shows me the history of one file, but I don't want to do this for a whole bunch of files.

Additionally, is there an easy way to `diff` all the files last modified by him in command line (against my last changes)? Thanks.

I am on a Mac if that matters.

Answer (score 2):

Log into Dropbox via the web interface and click the "Events" link on left-hand side of the page. This will show you what changes were made to which files and when they were made. Use the drop-down menu at the top to see the Events for specific folders.
[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is quite useful, although it would be more convenient if they would show each file only once, so that I don't have to scroll down a bunch of times to see more files.

Answer (score 0):

Go to view the folder on the Dropbox website. It shows who last modified each file (highlighting by me in red):

[image: Dropbox folder view]

Comment: Mine doesn't say that. Maybe because the folder is owned by my colleague?